# Background flash when viewing an answer directly doesn't seem to work

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript

I'm getting the following js errors per browser, on Win7:

- Firefox 9.01

  `h.end is undefined`
- Chrome 16.0.912.77 m

  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
- IE 9.0.8.112

  `SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined`

On `http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/stub.js?v=2bc4ea846933`.

What appears to be broken is the background flash when following a permalink to an answer. It [works on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-the-noobs/9961#9961), but it's broken on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books/392926#392926) and [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development/46760#46760), the background just stays orange.

Comment: We have just purged our CDN - can you try it again and let us know if you are having the same result?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Nope, same errors. But I'm still getting `stub.js?v=2bc4ea846933`, and it's different from the current version at the end, `var c={}})(jQuery);` vs `var c={transparent:[255,255,255]}})(jQuery);` respectively. By current, I mean what I get for `?v=blahblahblah_helloworld!`...

Comment: can you tell us what node you are hitting:  http://debug-02.netdna-cdn.com/

Comment: @GeoffDalgas NetDNA Amsterdam Datacenter

Comment: we have just purged all instances of stub.js - could you try again?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I'm still seeing that (Firefox 9.01 and Chrome 17/Linux) - same NetDNA datacenter as Yannis. Cleared all caches.

Comment: It appears that we have an issue with purging in our Amsterdam datacenter - I'll get back with an official response

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Everything back to normal, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something seems to be broken with the caching in the Amsterdam CDN node. It's still broken (I can see it as I'm hitting Amsterdam as well); I've contacted the CDN support about this.

But the file just got a new cache breaker, which forced the CDN to re-download a file, and thus you're getting the correct JavaScript now, so it works again.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me with Google Chrome. Maybe a local cache issue or something?